# Kibana 3.1.2 stats panel currency $ to £

Tags: kibana

I have Kibana 3.1.2 installed with a stats panel giving a total of a float which displays as configured as money. The problem being is that it's display in dollars not uk pounds. So with the $ rather than £.

I've looked but not found where I can change the currency that's work. I did find in the stats panel folder a js file (/app/panels/stats/module.js) with:

```
currency:{symbol:"$"}
```

I've changed the $ to a £ but it simply displayed a square box in front of the value. (Almost like the font was missing?)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Kibana on Github and their response is crisp and clear: it is not possible to use currency symbols other than dollar.

See https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1543

Comment: Please paste their response into your answer too. Questions and answers should have all the necessary information available on Stack Overflow itself rather than external sites. You can then link to that page to cite it.